# Error while adding new value in record type and updating metadata

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist, record-type

I habe a code that should add new picklist value in all RecordTypes but after run it i get an error in method *updateMetadata* **"System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not valid for type xsd:boolean, should be '0', '1', 'true' or 'false' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor"**. I use MetadataService from this [repo](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). Any suggestion to get it worked?

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort(); 
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomField picklistField = (MetadataService.CustomField) service
    .readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { 'Employee__c.Job_Title__c' }).getRecords()[0];

MetadataService.CustomValue[] pickVals = picklistField.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value;

/*
MetadataService.CustomValue newPickVal = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
newPickVal.fullName = 'New Picklist Value';
newPickVal.default_x = false;
newPickVal.isActive = null;
pickVals.add(newPickVal);
*/

String[] recordTypeNames = new String[] {'Hiring'};
MetadataService.Metadata[] mdRecordTypes = service.readMetadata('RecordType', recordTypeNames).getRecords();
MetadataService.RecordType[] recordTypes = (MetadataService.RecordType[]) mdRecordTypes;

MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue[] rtPickValues = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue[]{};
MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue rtPickValue = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue();
rtPickValue.picklist = 'Job_Title__c';
rtPickValue.values = pickVals;
rtPickValues.add(rtPickValue);
    
for(MetadataService.RecordType RT : recordTypes){
    RT.PicklistValues = rtPickValues;
    //System.debug(Json.serialize(RT.PicklistValues));
}

service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { mdRecordTypes[0] });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `isActive`, which must be `'true'` or `'false'`. It can't be an empty string.

Comment: For which class? @sfdcfox

Comment: @DenisTitarenko `newPickVal.isActive = null;` should be true or false. Also, currently commented out, but that's what you're missing.

Comment: @ sfdcfox Thanks, I tried to uncomment this piece of code and assigning the value true and the error is still there. The error appears when this piece of code is commented out, so probably the error is in another place

Comment: @DenisTitarenko Ah, well, you'll need to check the docs then. You've got a missing, required Boolean value.